# DLL made in C#, trying to import to another C# project (DLL can't be on root directory )

Tags: c#, dllimport, dllexport

Hi guys after a few hour searching and tying what i could find ( since most of I could find is the DLL made on C++ into a C# project and that is not what I want ) I come here with a question :D.

I'm trying to run the program, but want the DLL file to be on another directory ( For example the program is on c:\Programs\Program and DLL on c:\Libs ).

I have made an DLL in C# that have various methods public, that I want to have access in my program.

The DLL I have something like this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("6E873AA1-1AD6-4325-BBFD-EF22A3EB80CC")]
public interface ITraducoes
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    void changeLang(String lang);
    [ComVisible(true)]
    void translate(Control form);
    [ComVisible(true)]
    string toolTipText(Control form, String toolTip);
    [ComVisible(true)]
    string[] listText(Control form, String lista);
    [ComVisible(true)]
    string[] getMessagesArray();
    [ComVisible(true)]
    Hashtable getMessagesTable();
}
#region Traducoes Class
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid("AE53E0A3-8261-4706-8861-0249F7390642")]
//[ProgId("ITranslate.Traducoes")]
public class Traducoes : ITraducoes
{...
```

And on the programa I have something like this:

```
[DllImport("ITranslate.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern static void translate(Control form);
[DllImport("ITranslate.dll")]
extern static string[] getMessagesArray();
```

And then I call then like this:

```
public Form1(string[] args){
    InitializeComponent();                  
    translate(this);
    msg = getMessagesArray();
```

I hope I haven't miss anything, but if I do, I will do my best to provide it.

EDIT.

Forgot to say, that I'm geting this error

> Unable to find an entry point named 'translate' in DLL 'ITranslate.dll'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can't you just _reference_ the dll in your project?

Comment: I'm trying to import the DLL, normaly we just add a reference to it ( then it will copy to the root directory of the project ). I'm trying to put the DLL on a diferent root directy ( not the root directory of the project )

Answer (score 2):

You can't use DllImport to reference C# libraries.

Instead, add a reference to the DLL in your project and use it just as any other reference (eg. `System.Windows.Forms` etc.).

You don't have to have the class `ComVisible` or anything - all .NET assemblies expose all of their objects and metadata (somewhat limitable using `private` and such keywords, but in the end, you can get those too with a bit of work).

Comment: Yes but adding a reference, it will copy the DLL into the root of the project. But I don't want that. For example that same DLL could be by other programs, and would required o have the same DLL on program directory.

What I want is to share that DLL, having the DLL on ex. c:\Libs and the programs go there to get it.

Comment: @user3310091 You can use the `AssemblyResolve` event or the application manifest to do that. Or better yet, sign your library with a SNK, and it can be used straight from the GAC. Have a look at the ideas behind .NET assemblies, you're trying to solve the old problem the old way - .NET was designed to fix the DLL hell problem (how much it succeeded is a matter of a lively debate :D)

Comment: Thanks, it is possible to provide an example of it? :D

Comment: @user3310091 Try using this app.config / web.config section - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb(v=vs.110).aspx There's an example included.

Comment: With that the directory that contains the DLL must be also on the root  of the program Directory ( I did give a look into that before asking this question :D )

Comment: @user3310091 Actually, no. It just has to be strong named. If you can't have them strong named, `AssemblyResolve` might be the only way (you can load the assemblies from memory). However, the basic idea is that doing this is a bad idea :) The only libraries that should be shared are either residing in the same application base, or strong named asseblies (which can be in the GAC, anywhere on the computer or even anywhere on the LAN or the internet).